# encryption and decryption using php

Tags: php, encryption

I have the following code using for encryption

```
$key="company";
$value['service_id']="edit_details";
$encrypted_string=trim(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $value['service_id'], MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND))));
```

and i used the below code for decryption

```
$key="company";
$serviceId=$encrypted_string;
$decrypted_string=trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, base64_decode($serviceId), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND)));
```

I am not getting the original string edit_details.

I don't what is wrong in this.

Comment: how you get the `$encrypted_string` in the decryption section

Comment: by $_GET in the browser

Comment: Your code works just fine. I get `edit_details` as the decryption output

Comment: Did you save the $encrypted_string on bd before decoding?

Comment: I am just accessing the encrypted form of string and send it to the url and i receive it by $_GET and passed it to the decryption method.

Comment: http://localhost/mtonline/public/Company/ManageCompany/edit?id=3&service_name=H+LoAqdfiMv0XqN3mqJc6TMSF5U6rcEbCRX/XlTIopQ=          I am accessing the $encrypted_string by $_GET['service_name']

Comment: when i put the value of $value['service_id']="details_edit". it give me the same string as it is.But when i replace $value['service_id']="edit_details" it does not give me the same string after decryption why???

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using ECB, you don't need an initialization vector (IV) at all. Just remove it:

```
$key="company";
$value['service_id']="edit_details";
$encrypted_string=trim(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $value['service_id'], MCRYPT_MODE_ECB)));

$decrypted_string=trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, base64_decode($serviceId), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
```

In other modes, such as CBC, when an IV is needed, you're supposed to use the *same* IV for encryption and decryption. Pass it along with encrypted data, as shown on the [manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php).

This [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) explains how different block modes work.

Answer (score -1):

So if you are getting the value by `$_GET` use like this

```
$encrypted_string = trim(urlencode(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $value['service_id'], MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND)))));
```

when `base64_encoded` data is transferred , it may get corrupted if the data contains characters such as `?+/`. so `urlencode()` is needed when a data is transferred.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with their code. It works just fine. The issue lies somewhere else. Plus, after the edit you are trying to decrypt the unencrypted string.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky This is the encrypted string  `H+LoAqdfiMv0XqN3mqJc6TMSF5U6rcEbCRX/XlTIopQ= ` and if I get this in $_GET with out `urlencode()` then it will be `H LoAqdfiMv0XqN3mqJc6TMSF5U6rcEbCRX/XlTIopQ=` since it contains `+` chararcter in it , browser considers it as space. Thats my point

Comment: you are right browser automatically add the + sign whenever it find space

Comment: i got the exact issue and used `str_replace` for the `+` sign, got it working with a crypt function